# Trying to install Ruby on my mac but keep getting this "there is no executable" any suggestions?

Tags: ruby, macos

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Somehow it happened there is no executable 'openssl',
run 'brew doctor' and make sure latest '' is installed properly.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '4' =>
  'Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X).',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 12.
```

Comment: Did you run `rvm requirements` and see what it says?

Comment: @Casper all sorted now thanks for your comment, just typed the following to reset: rvm get stable, brew update, brew doctor, brew install openssl, rvm install ruby 5.0, rvm use ruby-5.0, rvm gemset create rails41, gem install rails -v5.0

Comment: Great :) You can answer and accept your own questions too. If you think it could help someone else then write it down as an answer and accept it.